# Convert Unicode Numbers to normal Number

Tags: php, mysql

I have some unicode number like ১ ২ ৩ ৪ ৫ ৬ ৭ ৮ ৯

i need to convert them into normal 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9

in order put them into my database.

Comment: use `str_replace`, make two array and use that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `str_repalce` to do this.

```
$bng = array("১", "২",  "৩");
$eng = array("1", "2", "3");
echo str_replace($bng, $eng, "১৩"); // 13
```